# I want to remove identity server from "ABP" angular app

Tags: angular, abp

ABP angular app redirect me for login on identity server which is not required. i want to keep user on my angular app with my own login page, register page. i want to use just simple identity tables which is full fill my requirements.
1- I complete the removal from server side ABP framework with the help of this https://community.abp.io/articles/replacing-identityserver4-with-identity-in-abp-arh0jxe1..
2- I want to remove identity server from ABP angular app,
3- I required custom login form on abp angular with simple identity controller token authentication.

ABP 4.3.3 , Angular, EF Core, SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

What is the question here?

What do you plan to put as STS after removing identityserver? **Identityser is not about identity management.** It uses default aspnet identity library if you want to keep your userstore in the same server.

For short, **you need to create your own AuthServer** that handles token authentication, refreshing, validation etc. It can reside in your own backend (api) or in a different server.

If your question is **if there is any default authentication server for .Net Core SPA apps**, yes; it is IdentityServer. Even Microsoft didn't want to bother with it and used IdentityServer. They may come up with a default solution for Authentication Server soon since IdentityServer became commercial if you can wait.

If your question is, **how to create your own authentication server?** You need lots of googling and learning about security standarts. Then start implementing jwt token authentication and trying not to compromize security.